# Python Tkinter: How to make Infinite Loop function in a button withouth crash?

Tags: python, loops, button, tkinter

I have tried to make Infinite Loop function but the interface always hangs without doing anything.
I tried doing a while loop and then also with `.after()` and the result is always the same. Can someone help me please?

```
def start_ping():
    
    while True:
        
        indices_tabla = tabla.get_children()
        
        for x_fila in range(0,len(indices_tabla)):
            
            celda_ip = tabla.item(indices_tabla[x_fila], 'values')[0]
            ping_equipo = ping(str(celda_ip), count=4)
                           
            msg = (celda_ip + '\n' +
                   '\n' +
                   str(datetime.now()) + '\n' +
                   '\n' +
                   str(ping_equipo) + '\n' +
                   '\n' +
                   '--------------------------------------------------' + '\n' + '\n')
            
            text_box.insert(tk.END, msg)

            text_box.yview(tk.END)
            
            celda_p_enviados =  int(tabla.item(indices_tabla[x_fila], 'values')[1])
            
            
            
            tabla.insert("", tk.END, text=str(lista_equipos[x_fila]),
                                 values=(str(lista_pings[x_fila]),celda_p_enviados+4,"0"))
            
            tabla.delete(indices_tabla[x_fila])
            

btn_start_ping = tk.Button(ventana, text="Start Ping!",
                       command= lambda: start_ping()).grid(row=2 , column=0)
```

Comment: `ping()` may take few seconds to complete, so it will block tkinter from handling pending tasks.  Use thread to run `start_ping()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after` to call a function after a given number of milliseconds. If a function uses `after` to call itself after a delay, you've essentially created an infinite loop.

Step 1, create a function that calls another function every second:

```
def call_forever(func, *args):
    func(*args)
    root.after(1000, call_forever, *args)
```

Step 2, create a function that does one iteration:

```
def do_something():
    <put whatever code you want here>
```

Step 3, call the second function once to start the loop:

```
call_forever(do_something)
```

If you want your function to be able to break out of the loop, have the inner function return a boolean, and the outer function use the result to determine if it should continue.

```
def call_forever(func, *args):
    should_continue = func(*args)
    if should_continue:
        root.after(1000, call_forever, func, *args)

def do_something():
    <put whatever code you want here>
    return True  # or return False if you want the loop to stop
```